# Как вставить картинку в фон?

Tags: html, css

Прошу о помощи друзья! Я начинающий. Я хотел бы вставить картинку в свой код. Но не знаю как правильно это сделать. Я вставил вроде бы как картинку в тег "body". Но при этом. Картинка вставлена будто бы в сетку.
Проблема в том. Что картинка не одна. Вот код:

`<body bgcolor="#000" background="logo.png">`

Как исправить? Что бы картинка была одна на весь экран. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url(logo.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-attachment: fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: постарайтесь добавлять более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit]